# Integral equation, Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Find all functions $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R} $, that solve

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t-x)f(x) dx =e^{-t^2}$, $ t\in \mathbb{R}$

How do I solve this?

I know that the left part is the convolution $(f\ast f)(t)$.

Comment: Is $f\in L^1$? If so, it reduces the possibilities a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Taking the Fourier Transform of both sides, we get
$$
\hat{f}^2(\tau)=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi^2\tau^2}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?